# Nested model forms with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having more trouble with nested forms.  This time with my polymorphic Address model.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<%= form_for @account do |f| %>

<%= f.label :account_type %><br />
<%= f.text_field :account_type %><br />

    <%= f.fields_for :organizations do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label :name %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :name %><br />
        <%= builder.label :website %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :website %><br />

        <%= builder.fields_for :locations do |lb| %>
            <%= lb.label :phone %><br />
            <%= lb.text_field :phone %><br />
            <%= lb.label :toll_free_phone %><br />
            <%= lb.text_field :toll_free_phone %><br />
            <%= lb.label :fax %><br />
            <%= lb.text_field :fax %><br />

            <%= lb.fields_for :address do |ab| %>
                <%= ab.label :address1 %><br />
                <%= ab.text_field :address1 %><br />
                <%= ab.label :address2 %><br />
                <%= ab.text_field :address2 %><br />
                <%= ab.label :city %><br />
                <%= ab.text_field :city %><br />
                <%= ab.label :state %><br />
                <%= ab.text_field :state %><br />
                <%= ab.label :zip %><br />
                <%= ab.text_field :zip %><br />
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Add account" %>
<% end %>

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :organizations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :account

    has_many :locations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :organization

    has_one :address, :as => :addressable

end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

class AccountsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @account = Account.new
    organization = account.organizations.build
    location = organization.locations.build
    location.addresses.build

    @header = "Create account"
end

def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
        #handle success
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
end
```

When trying to display the form via /accounts/new I am getting the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in AccountsController#new

undefined method `addresses' for #<Location:0x18d7718>
Rails.root: C:/Documents and Settings/Corey Quillen/My     
Documents/rails_projects/shop_manager

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:7:in `new'
Request

Parameters:

None
```

Comment: When posting questions please separate out the individual concerns of your code into separate, titled blocks. This makes it easier for potential answerers to interpret your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're doing `location.addresses.build` when you've defined the Address association for this model as a `has_one`. As such, you will need to do `location.build_address`. The same thing goes for if you were ever looking to build a `belongs_to` association.

It is not possible for the `build` method to be called on the `address` association itself, as the `address` method would attempt to load the associated object and return `nil` if it can't, and calling `build` on `nil` is just not allowed. Therefore, you need to do `build_address`.